# Google Sheets Split Transpose Join

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

All, I am attempting to parse a column, transpose its contents and join it to another column. I have seen a few variations of how to accomplish with a mix of ARRAYFORMULA(), TRANSPOSE(), SPLIT() which almost works but most of them filter out blanks. In my case, the column being parsed may have rows with blanks which is perfectly normal. Sample input and desired output below and shared sheet. Thanks in advance.

[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OCJU5BGAWMt99cuufWlsua0oNCZCYjrEEFfH-YWbj4Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(UNIQUE(IFERROR(SPLIT({IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((
 IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";"))<>""),"♦"&A2:A&"♣"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";")), )),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦"))}, "♣")))))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(UNIQUE(IFERROR(SPLIT({
 IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A&"♣ ♣"&ROW(A2:A), B2:B="", A2:A<>"")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((
 IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";"))<>""),"♦"&A2:A&"♣"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";"))&"♣"&ROW(A2:A), ))
 ,,99^99)),,99^99), "♦"))}, "♣"))), 3, 1), 99^99, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Additional note for reference: The 2nd solution is more ideal as it removes some spacing at the end of the parsed string and resolved some knock on formula issues in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This might also work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A23&"|"&SPLIT(IF(B2:B23="","#",B2:B23),";")),"|",0,0),"where Col2<>''"),"#",""))
```

Comment: @player0 A user in the google forums discovered a HIDDEN function with no documentation!