# Is there a neat way of formatting a 3 column array in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, concatenation, multiple-columns, textjoin

Using Google Sheets, I would like to save space, when I render the output from a filter and query, by placing the key value from "Dept" in column 1 as a header over "Member" and "Code" in columns 2 and 3.

Thus far I have only found that I can achieve this with tedious manual copying and some conditional formatting. I wonder if there might be way using inbuilt Google Sheets functions but, I guess that I might have to write an Apps Script.

[image: Table Transformation]

Herewith a link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SUcqfudwZuXasFHKxXbiTns9s2fvCKJAtUVk8LuisSQ/edit?usp=sharing

I want to create Table E. I am struggling with trying to join the two input tables A & B on the "Member" field to form Table C. I can get the result with several messy steps in between but have failed to find an efficient, single formula method with multiple attempts using ARRAYFORMULA(), TRANSPOSE(), SPLIT() and TEXTJOIN() in various combinations.

The following image is a refinement of that which I posted earlier.

[image]

Many thanks for your help! Here is an answer thanks to Matt King:

```
=sort(query(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(E5:K5&"|"&IF(E6:K12="","#",E6:K12)),"|",0,0),"where Col2 <>''"),"#","")),"select * where Col2 is not null"),1,1,2,1)
```

Comment: The first step, as ever, is going to be to share the data in a way that the volunteer contributors here can easily access (i.e., not an image). I recommend that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet that already has test data entered, and that you indicate where in the sheet you hope to have the output (i.e., the resulting list).

Comment: Many thanks Erik. I will definitely take on board your suggestions to share the link to samples in future. I do have a follow up question which I shall post later.

Comment: I still invite you to share a link to a spreadsheet for this post, as I would have shared a different approach. The solution offered by player0 assumes you know where your "dept" lines will fall and that they will always fall in the same place, which is unlikely. Once those move, given that merged cells were introduced, you'll have quite a problem.

Comment: Thanks Erik, as you suggested: I have posted a link with another image to illustrate the problem.

Comment: ... I found the answer, thanks to Matt King at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726898/4483909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN({IF(
 COUNTIFS(A2:A10, A2:A10, ROW(A2:A10), "<="&ROW(A2:A10))=1, A2:A10, ), 
 B2:B10&"×"&C2:C10}), "×")), "where Col1 is not null and Col1 <> '×'", ))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(F2:F15="",,ROW(E2:E15)), 
 FILTER({ROW(E2:E15), E2:E15}, F2:F15=""), 2, 1)), E2:F15}, 
 "where Col3 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you @player0. You have set me on a path that has helped enormously to begin to understand how to use array handling functions in formulae to make my sheets both more efficient and readable. Your first offering was what I was looking for but, your second offering also provides valuable insight.

I have further modified my formulae, (for which a link, see above): I have included VLOOKUPS. A real challenge is to try to derive Table E from Tables A & B without generating intermediate Tables C & D.

Thereafter I must tackle the merged cell formatting with an App script.